# Youtube iframe embed loading flash player instead of HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

When I try to use iframe embedding for youtube video it sometimes loads HTML5 player and sometimes flash player.

Specifically, this `<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE"></iframe>` will load flash player whereas `<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/Zti5s48tc7k"></iframe>`will load HTML5 player.

When I open both the videos in YouTube website both of them load in HTML5 players.
I cannot figure out why different videos load in different players.

Answer (score 0):

it sound like video comparability so deepened how youtube video stored in their server they provide different player so the video played correctly. I think this happened with old video and there is nothing you can do about it.

Note: this is just person guessing of the issue.